# Access is Denied when Reset-ComputerMachinePassword is run through Invoke-command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I'm using the following command to reset a remote machine'
s password.

```
$user="Domain\domainadmin";
$pass="dapassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;
$creds=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $pass;
Invoke-Command -Credential $creds -ComputerName "DomainControllerMachine" -ScriptBlock{ 
$ComputerName = @"
SomeRemoteHost
"@
Import-Module ActiveDirectory; 
Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server ${ComputerName};
}
```

I keep getting 'Access is denied' error.

```
This command cannot be executed on target computer('DomainControllerMachine') due to following error: Access is
 denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (DomainControllerMachine:String) [Reset-ComputerMachinePasswor
   d], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ResetCompute
   rMachinePasswordCommand
```

The account I use has all levels of access to the ActiveDirectory. So there won't be a issue with the credentials used for authentication.

If I run the same command on the 'DomainControllerMachine' (logged in as same user) it works fine.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory; 
Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server "SomeRemoteHost";
```

Even the whole invoke-command block above just works without complaining on the DomainControllerMachine.
But when I do it remotely through Invoke-Command, or Enter-PSSession I get that dreaded access denied error..

I've also tried using CredSSP after setting up the WSManCredSSP (Client, delegation and Server) on the machines with no luck.

I may have missed something, or is there a better way to handle such a case?

Comment: Are you doing this from the same machine that your resetting the account on?

Comment: Have you tried perhaps storing the invoked commands as a script on the target machine then using invoke to run that script? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7bcea69-628b-4deb-8a1d-b080a652e16f/powershell-invokecommand-admodule

Comment: Run your powershell session in elevated prompt(right click-> _Run as Administrator_)

Comment: @mjolinor no, they are different machines

Comment: @Raf Yeah, I always do. The shell is run as administrator.

Comment: have you tried using `-Authentication Kerberos` parameter for `Invoke-Command` and running as an account with domain admin?  Is this a script or are you executing these commands in the shell directly?

Comment: @Raf thank you! totally missed this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are running the Reset-computermachinepassword command on the domaincontroller. As far as I know it should be run on the computer that needs to be reset with the DC name in the -server field.

To do this you would need to run the command on the computer that needs it's credentials reset:

```
Reset-Computermachinepassword -server "DomainControllerMachine" -credential $PScredential
```

You can try to do it remotely with a PSsession if the computer has powershell remoting enabled. You will need to specify a different authentication method to reach a computer that has lost it's trust with the domain.

You can use Credssp but this will only work if your GPO allows delegating your credentials to the target computer.
Or you can use Basic authentication. But for that to work the Target must accept unencrypted traffic.

The command to do it remotely would probably look something like this:

```
$session = new-PSSession "targetcomputer" -Authentication Basic -Credential  "Domain\domainadmin"
Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock {Reset-Computermachinepassword -server "Domain\domainadmin"}
```

Comment: Close.  I get `Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'.  The argument is null or empty.  Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again`.  I also replaced your `-server "Domain\domainadmin"` with `-server "myserver.domain.com"`, but that's all I did.  But it was a good answer in that it explained you can't run the command on the DC and expect it to update the affected server without doing the hocus-pocus.